# Setting custom page width and height using QGIS Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I need to produce a number of squared images with QGis Composer (QGis 2.14.11-Essen). There is a multitude of pre-set page formats but they are all rectangular. I would like to provide my own width and height page settings, e.g. 200x200 mm. How can it be done?

---

There is no way to modify the contents of the *Width* and *Height* boxes in the *Page Setup* dialogue:

[image]

Comment: What about selecting `Custom` and setting 200 to the width and height settings with units set to `mm`?

Comment: to add to joseph: it should be the very first option on the list

Comment: What is your QGIS version?

Comment: @Joseph: the width and height boxes in the Page Setup dialog are greyed out, it is not possible to modify their contents. Please check the image I am adding to the question.

Comment: @ArMoraer: it is 2.14.11-Essen, I am adding that information to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open or create a print composer on the Tab "Composition" you can choose "Custom" from the drop-down menu and thus change the width and height to your liking. In addition, you also can choose the units of measurement.

**EDIT**:

tested with 2.18 and 2.14 and in both cases, I can change the page size when choosing "custom" option. When the tab "Composer is missing, you can readd it under view -> Planels -> Composition

Here a small gif to show you how I did it. 
[image]

Comment: I do not have a "Composition" tab, only "Item properties".

Comment: @LuísdeSousa under view -> Panels you should be able to add the composer tab

Comment: Good. Please add that information to your answer.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa added a gif which shows the whole process hope it helps :)

Comment: @gisnside I use [screentogif](https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif/wiki/Help)the link is to there github site. here the link to the "main" page http://www.screentogif.com/

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is having this issue in QGIS 3, the settings are hidden (for now?)...

- Right-click the page
- Choose 'Page Size'
- The 'Item Properties' panel now contains your page size settings (it doesn't normally show them)

This is a strange method to get to the page size, as I'm seeing issues even using the menu Layout > Page size on various operating systems to no avail.

Lastly, this answer came from: 
[How to change page size in QGIS Composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262497/how-to-change-page-size-in-qgis-composer) 
which again came from Reddit :-)