Method to subset a GeoTIFF image based on pre-defined grid
I have a GeoTIFF image of an agricultural field and surrounding area that I'm working with in QGIS. I've defined a couple of grids in QGIS to generate zonal stats for target plant sets. This has worked well, now I'd like to extract separate GeoTIFF plant images based on my existing grids. Ideally, I'd like to extract a GeoTIFF image for each grid cell, preferably with a filename corresponding to the fid or id field in the QGIS grid attribute table.
I'm new to working with GIS software and was unable to find a solution while digging through the docs. Searching lead to a few solutions that were close, but didn't apply to my situation. I'm now wondering if it would be better to use the "left/top/right/bottom" coords from the QGIS grid attribute table in a Python script to extract the images. I have no experience with the Python gis and image processing modules. There seem to be many possible avenues to explore.
Can you point me in the right direction?

As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question even if all but one of them are unmarked.

"Best" questions are intrinsically opinion-based, and therefore off-topic here. Our Focused question/Best answer model works best when you compose the entire question first, then generate a simple statement that describes the subject of the Question, as a title, to advertise your Question to local experts .  Posing a Boolean question in the question body is case study in asking the wrong question, since Answers are expected to span several paragraphs, and "Yes" or "No" are too short to qualify as an Answer.

Thanks, Bera, I look forward to your response.

The post states "I'd like to extract a GeoTIFF image for each grid cell, preferably with a filename corresponding to the fid or id field in the QGIS grid attribute table." I've provided background info along with solutions I've tried or considered. There are not multiple questions, Boolean or otherwise. Can you be more specific about what the issue with the post is?

You can use an atlas in the print composer to create an image of each one.
Have only the raster layer visible.
Make a print composer.
Set up the Atlas generator:
Choose your grid as the Coverage layer.
Tick the Hidden coverage layer.
Untick the Single file export when possible. This will let you change the Output filename expressionemphasized text to be driven by the coverage layer, so use the fid if you want.

Add a map to cover the whole print composer.
Then in the map Item Properties.
Choose:
Controlled by Atlas.
Set Margin around feature to 0%.
Then you can turn on the Atlas Preview and it will zoom to one of the grids. And exporting the atlas to images will produce one image per grid cell.


Thanks for the detailed response. This is very close, the only issue I've ran into is with the output aspect ratio. Even with the map "Controlled by Atlas" and 0% "Margin around feature" set, my images are being exported at 3507 px wide x 2480 px high. The grid cells are roughly 4:1 width:height and I can see that the exported images are capturing the correct width, but it is adding extra height above and below the grid cell. Looking closer at the map item properties, I can see under "Position and Size", width = 297 and height = 210. Can this be set automatically from the grid?

You can set the size of the page: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/286059/16530

Selecting Layout -> Resize Layout to Content -> Resize layout didn't change anything for me, but I was able to manually set the size using Item Properties -> Position and Size -> Width/Height.
